# Why is this true for any x and y where x and y are whole numbers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$x,y,z ∈ Z$

$∀x∀y∃z((x < z) ⇒ (x ≥ y))$

We know that to prove it wrong, we just have to find a counterexample. That means we have to find $T⇒F$. If we have: $x=2$. Sure, there exists a z that is larger than x. But why is it given that x also then is larger than or equals to y? Can't we just set $z=5, y=1$ and have a counterexample?

Comment: what do you mean by $->$ symbol?

Comment: @AbdallahHammam ⇒, fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your proposition is equivalent to

$\forall (x,y)\in \mathbb Z^2$ there exists $z\in \mathbb Z$ such that

$x\geq z$ or $x\geq y$.

It is always true if we take $z=x-1$.

Comment: @Masacroso P imply Q is equivalent to notP or Q.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam yes, you are right. I see now.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I figured it out. You can just choose an z where $z \leq x$. Then it will always be true.

Comment: No, you choose z not x.